# Select Product which have x tags in Symfony Doctrine Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need your help.

Situation:

I have two entity Products and Tags.(many to many)
For example I have product "car" which have tags: "red" and "sport"
Next I have search form with checkbox for tags, user can select tag red or sport or both and click search. After that I want have product which have one or more selected tags.

I want to use query builder but I dont know What I should to do?

```
>$category= $form->get('category')->getData();

>$tags = $form->get('tags')->getData();

>$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Product');

>$qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
->select('p, t, c')
->leftJoin('p.category', 'c')
->leftJoin('p.tags', 't');

//for category

>if(isset($category) && $category!= NULL){
$qb->andWhere('c.slug = :category')
->setParameter('category', $category->getSlug());
}
```

//for tags ???

What next? Please help me.

Comment: Isn't `->andWhere('t IN :tags')->setParameter('tags', $tags);` what you want ? This give you a product that have at least one of the `$tags`. Maybe need to specify a field (i.e. `t.id IN tagIds`, and build an array of tag ids), I'm not sure.

Comment: `$qb ->andWhere('t IN (:tags)')->setParameter('tags', $tags);` This maybe will work.

Comment: Very good eye @MateuszMal, thanks.

Comment: This should give you results that have __at least one tag__ of `$tags`.

Comment: I have small problem with this because when I have product which have tags: "red", "small" and i filter from form search by on tag for exaple "red". In result I have this product but in his entity tag i see only tag "red", another tag which this product has dissapear.

Comment: I don't think it's related to the query, right ? Maybe ask another question related to this specific problem.

Comment: When I show all product I have normal all tags from product, after submit form with this select I have only tag in product tags which I selected. I dont know why.

Comment: I need more informations to understand what you are doing after submitting the form in order to know what you expect. If you want, you can try to add more code, but I think creating another question would be more adapted, because it's a totally different problem.

Comment: II think that this is because we filter tag table not product.tags table. Do you know what about I talk? It should be somethink like this : `$qb
                ->andWhere('h.tags IN (:tags)')->setParameter('tags', $tags);` but it not work. We cut tags from product which will be show as result. This result product show me that he has only selected tags but he has another more tags and this tags was dissapear

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$qb
    ->select('p, t, c')
    // ...
    ->andWhere('t IN (:tags)')
    ->setParameter('tags', $tags);
```

Thank you @MateuszMal for the correction.